# mysql order by date and sort parent table

Tags: mysql, join, doctrine, sql-order-by, doctrine-query

i have this two table:

```
id | name
1  | Mike
2  | Jack

id | id_client | title | due_date   | sort
1  | 1         | Xxxx  | 2016-01-22 | 0
2  | 1         | Xxxx  | 2016-01-24 | 1
3  | 2         | Xxxx  | 2016-01-28 | 0
```

I need to order the first by date, and the second by sort. I have try this but not work:

```
->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("a.*","b.*")
            ->from("table_a", "a")
            ->leftJoin("a", "table_b", "b", "a.id = b.id_client")
            ->addOrderBy('b.due_date', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('b.sort', 'ASC')
```

Any help?

Comment: Is the incorrect `due_date` column name really in your code, or a copying error?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` if you're ordering by a column in the table you're joining? What date should it use if there's no match?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `leftJoin` correctly? I don't use Doctrine, but I looked at a few examples and they don't look like that.

Comment: was a copying error. the column is due_date

Comment: What specifically is the problem, "not work" isn't clear enough. Do you get an error? Are you getting the correct data but the wrong order?

Answer (score 0):

According to your example code you're trying to sort by 'due_date' from table B but the column's actually named 'date'. You don't say exactly what issue(s) you're having but I would start by resolving that mismatch - best to rename the column as 'date' is a reserved word in mySQL and using it may be an issue in itself.